# Basic Integral Understanding

Tags: calculus

This is a basic question about how to solve integrals/Riemann Sums. I am just starting to learn about them, and so I am trying to get the basics.

The limit of a Riemann Sum is

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_{i}) \Delta x_{i}$$

I want to know how you find $\Delta x$ when given a problem. 
For example, if $f(x) = x^{2}$ and is on the $[0,2]$, how would you set up and then solve the problem?

I know that it is $\frac {b-a}{n}$, but do you then do another step? Or, it could be I am mixing up information and this whole question makes no sense.

I know this is a very basic question, but if anyone could help me out, it would be great.

Comment: Maybe useful : [Riemann integral : Definition and Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Definition).

Comment: Please, be more specific when you say that you want to know how one finds $\Delta x$. And what steps exactly are you talking about? Could you give us a simple example?

Comment: Its hard for me to be specific because I am just starting to learn this so I don't really have any grasp on it yet. But, does this edit help?

Comment: It might be easier to draw a small diagram for some $f >0$ and see how you would estimate the area between $f$ and the $x$-axis using vertical rectangles.

Comment: modernstates.org also might help you out. You can enroll in their calculus course (it's all free) and there are a series of videos that might help you. It really is a CLEP studying resource, but you may find it helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example with $n=4$ showing the right Riemann sum:
[image]
The curve is $y=x^2$ and I divided $[0,2]$ into four intervals, then chose $x_i$ to be the right endpoint so that the left interval would have a rectangle.  You could obviously use much larger $n$ but it would be hard to draw.  The sum for $n=4$ is the sum of the areas of the four rectangles you see.  The idea is that you imagine doing this construction for larger and larger $n$, then take the limit of the sum as $n \to \infty$

For $n$ subdivisions, as you say $\Delta x=\frac 2n$.  Also $x_i=\frac {2i}n$ with $i$ ranging from $1$ to $n$.  So the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\frac 2n=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac {2i}n\right)^2\frac 2n\\=\frac 8{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac 8{n^3}\frac 16n(n+1)(2n+1)
\\=\frac {16n^3+24n^2+8n}{6n^3}$$
If we take the limit of this as $n \to \infty$ we get $\frac 83$

Comment: To find $x_{i}$ do you always multiply $\Delta x$ by $x_{i}$?

Comment: If you use equal width intervals, which is convenient but not required, the $x_i$ are equally spaced.  If you take $x_i$ as the right hand end of the interval, you have $x_i=a+(b-a)\frac in$  This is the algebra of an arithmetic progression, not calculus.