# Follow-Up Question (How to Solve Integrals/Riemann Sums)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

This is really a follow-up question to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295803/basic-integral-understanding).

I asked: 
*This is a basic question about how to solve integrals/Riemann Sums. I am just starting to learn about them, and so I am trying to get the basics.
The limit of a Riemann Sum is
$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_{i}) \Delta x_{i}$$
I want to know how you find \Delta x when given a problem. For example, if $f(x) = x^{2}$ and is on the $4[0,2]$, how would you set up and then solve the problem?
I know that it is $\frac {b-a}{n}$, but do you then do another step? Or, it could be I am mixing up information and this whole question makes no sense.
I know this is a very basic question, but if anyone could help me out, it would be great.*

The answer I got from @RossMilken was:
 *For $n$ subdivisions, as you say $\Delta x=\frac 2n$. Also $x_i=\frac {2i}n$ with $i$ ranging from $1$ to $n$. So the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\frac 2n=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac {2i}n\right)^2\frac 2n\\=\frac 8{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac 8{n^3}\frac 16n(n+1)(2n+1)
\\=\frac {16n^3+24n^2+8n}{6n^3}$$
If we take the limit of this as $n \to \infty$ we get $\frac 83$*

This was really helpful, and now I want to know what you do differently to find the upper and lower sum.

So, my question is:
**Do you do anything differently when looking specifically for the upper or lower sum?**

Comment: Upper sums require us to find the maximum value in each subinterval of the Riemann sum, while lower sums involve the minimum value.  Both of them are choices of the point $x_i$ used to evaluate the integrand in respective subintervals.  So in a sense you are doing the same thing, but it may be difficult to find exactly those extreme values (not so hard when the function is monotonic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual definition of the Riemann Integral relies on the limit of the upper sum being equal to the limit of the lower sum. To compute either the upper or lower sum take the supremum/infimum maximum/minimum of each interval that you are dividing up.

So the upper sum can be written

$U = \sum \sup(f(x_i), f(x_{i+1}))\Delta x_i$
and the lower sum can be written:

$L = \sum \inf(f(x_i), f(x_{i+1}))\Delta x_i$
And if 
$\lim_{n\to\infty} U = \lim_{n\to\infty} L$

That is the definition of the Riemann Integral of the function $f$.

Something important to remember is that you are taking intervals, of a function not the values at points. Also if you are confused at all about supremum and infimum vs max and min essentially they are a precise definition because they do not require the function to reach that minimum or maximum. For example the function $\frac1x$ doesn't have a minimum in the interval $[1,\infty]$ but its infimum is $0$.

Comment: Re: First  sentence. The upper and lower sums are almost never equal. The $limits$ of these sums (as the fineness of the partitions  converges to $0$) are equal for a Riemann-integrable function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the limit of a Riemann sum, the upper and lower sums are equal. The Reimann Sum can be drawn by drawing rectangles under the graph of $f(x)$. The upper sum is when the rectangles are drawn using the right points of each subinterval, and the lower sum is drawn by using the left point of each subinterval. As the subintervals get smaller and smaller, the difference between the upper and lower sum disappears. Therefore, there is no difference between the upper and lower sum.